# Load, edit and update xml file by html form php

Tags: php, xml, forms, simplexml

I'm trying to make a script to read an XML file, insert it in a form and edit and update the values using php.

The form loads the present data, but does not update them.

Can anyone tell me a tip?
Thanks Maurizio

**file XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myxml>

  <data name="en_title"><![CDATA[mytitle]]></data>
  <data name="en_scene_title"><![CDATA[ES000021903]]></data>

</myxml>
```

**file edit PHP**

```
<?php
$form_fields  = null;
$data = simplexml_load_file('messages_en.xml');
foreach($data->data as $field)
{

  $form_fields .= '<div>';
    $form_fields .=  '<label>' .$field['name'] . ' </label>';
    $form_fields .=  '<input type="text" id="' .$field['name'] . '"placeholder="'.htmlentities($field).'" name="'.$field. '" />';
    $form_fields .= '</div>';
  }
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <style>
      form { font-size: 16px; }
      form div { margin: .3em; }
      legend { font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; }
      label { display:inline-block; width: 140px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" action="process.php">
      <legend> Enter Contact Information</legend>
      <?php echo $form_fields; ?>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn"  />
    </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**code file process.php**

```
<?php
    $xml = file_get_contents('messages_en.xml');
    $sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    if(isset($sxml->item[$_POST['name']])) {
        $node->data = $_POST['name'];
    }
    file_put_contents('messages_en.xml', $sxml->asXML());
?>
```

Comment: Better use DOMDocument

Comment: @LarsStegelitz nothing wrong with using SimpleXML.

Comment: What is `$node`?

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with SimpleXML but isn't `$sxml` going to contain an array of the two `data` elements?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to update the XML based on the `name` attribute of the `<data>` element?

If so, you need to a) pass both the name and the value from your HTML, and b) search for the name you want.

```
$var = $_POST["name"];
$val = $_POST["value"];

$xml = file_get_contents("messages_en.xml");
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
// find the data element with the matching attribute
$node = $xpath->query("/myxml/data[@name='$var']");
// assume there's only one, otherwise we can loop
// clear the existing content
$node[0]->textContent = "";
// create a new CDATA section
$node[0]->appendChild($dom->createCDATASection($val));
// save the updated XML
file_put_contents("messages_en.xml", $dom->saveXml());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I need to change the value inside tag ( in bold ) 

example : 

<data name="en_title"><![CDATA[**mytitle**]]></data>

is it possible to do so?, unfortunately the xml file is not generated by me and I cannot change it. thx

Comment: You don't really need the CDATA section, but there it is anyway.

Comment: The script works, but not in my server, the module does not pass the variables from the module ... what could it be?